# Validator.TryValidateProperty throws ArgumentException

Tags: c#, validation, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, attributes

I use ListValidation

```
public class Test
    {

        [ListValidation(ErrorMessage ="wrong")]
        public List<string> Listt { get; set; }
    }
```

ListValidation implementation

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class ListValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            var list = value as IList;
            if (list != null)
            {
                return list.Count > 0;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

when I test it

```
Test t = new Test();
            List<string> str = new List<string>();
            str.Add("haha");
            str.Add("hoho");

            t.Listt = str;

            JsonResult json = ModelValidation.ValidateProperty(t, nameof(t.Listt));
```

It throws `ArgumentException`

```
{System.ArgumentException: The value for property 'Listt' must be of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.
Parameter name: value
   at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.EnsureValidPropertyType(String propertyName, Type propertyType, Object value)
   at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.TryValidateProperty(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext, ICollection`1 validationResults)
   at EArchive.Infrastructure.ModelValidation.ValidateProperty(Object obj, String property) in C:\Users\haha\ModelValidation.cs:line 54}
```

ValidateProperty implementation

```
public static JsonResult ValidateProperty(object obj, string property)
        {
            ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(obj)
            {
                MemberName = property
            };

            List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();



            bool valid = Validator.TryValidateProperty(property, context, results);

            if (!valid) // there is no error and everything is good
            {
                return null;
            }

            string errors = "";

            // fetch all errors happened in the property.
            foreach (ValidationResult result in results)
            {
                errors += result.ErrorMessage + "\n <br>";
            }


            Dictionary<string, string> err = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "status", "fail" },
                    { "message", errors }
                };

            return new JsonResult(err);

        }
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Validator.TryValidateProperty` expects the first argument (`object value`) to be the value to test for the property rather than the name of it. In your example, you are passing the string `Listt` instead of the value *of* `t.Listt`. In order to get this to work for your purposes, you'll need to change your `ValidateProperty` function, as follows:

```
public static JsonResult ValidateProperty(object propertyValue, string propertyName, object sourceObject)
{
    ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(sourceObject)
    {
            MemberName = propertyName
    };

    List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();

    bool valid = Validator.TryValidateProperty(propertyValue, context, results);

    // ...
```

Then, just update your call-site accordingly:

```
JsonResult json = ModelValidation.ValidateProperty(t.Listt, nameof(t.Listt), t);
```

Here's a blog post I used as inspiration for this answer: https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/simple-validation-with-data-annotations/.